# Cannot find module 'entities/maps/xml.json' from 'Tokenizer.js'

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, create-react-app

I have created a react application using create-react-app, and I am attempting to use enzyme to do a simple test of a simple component.

Header.test.js:

```
import Header from './Header';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('Header component', () => {
   it('renders correctly', () => {
       const wrapper = shallow(<Header />);
       expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting this error:

```
  Cannot find module 'entities/maps/xml.json' from 'Tokenizer.js'

        at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:221:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/cheerio/node_modules/htmlparser2/lib/Tokenizer.js:6:17)
```

My hunch is that it's something to do with webpack but I'm not sure... help!

Oh yeah and this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.8",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.5.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.19.0",
    "react": "^16.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.6.1",
    "reactstrap": "^6.5.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^6.1.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.7.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.7.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.4",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.4.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `node_modules`, run `yarn install`

At least for me it worked.